# How do you set config file for Prometheus?

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I installed prometheus but get stuck at:
First run Prometheus, using the prometheus-near.yml config file located in the ./conf directory of this repository:
$ prometheus --config.file=$PATH_TO_REPO/conf/prometheus-near.yml

Answer (score 1):

Installing Prometheus is basically downloading the compressed binary for your platform and unpacking locally ([per the documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/#downloading-and-running-prometheus)). The `prometheus` binary is located inside that folder. To [start prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/#starting-prometheus) use:

```
$> ./prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml
```

If you want to use a different config file, as suggested by your question, just provide the path to the config file as the argument to `config.file` like:

```
$> ./prometheus --config.file=/path/to/config/prometheus-near.yml
```

You should be able to query prometheus server at port `9090`.

Comment: I run: `~/prometheus-2.19.0.linux-amd64# ls
LICENSE  console_libraries  data        prometheus-near.yml  promtool
NOTICE   consoles           prometheus  prometheus.yml       tsdb
root@ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1:~/prometheus-2.19.0.linux-amd64# ./prometheus --config.file=prometheus-near.yml` and the error is `level=error ts=2020-06-16T14:30:02.977Z caller=main.go:758 err="error loading config from \"prometheus-near.yml\": couldn't load configuration (--config.file=\"prometheus-near.yml\"): parsing YAML file prometheus-near.yml: yaml: line 118: mapping values are not allowed in this context"`

Comment: It seems the `prometheus-near.yml` you are using is malformed.